# Need help on Loading Failed for Socket.io.js

Tags: node.js, apache, ssl, socket.io

I just got my ssl certificate from GoDaddy, and I am now running the website in https://example.com and my socketio server in http://example.com:3000 (it can't access socketio in https)

This is the error message I am getting from my console

"Loading failed for the  with source “https://example.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js”

This is how I am adding the socket.io.js

```
<script src="<?php print BASE_URL; ?>:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Here is my nodejs server with socket.io

```
var app = require('express')();
var cors = require('cors');
var https = require('https').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(https);
var _ = require('lodash');

// more include files here ...

https.listen(3000, function() {
  utils.logger('Listening on *: 3000', 'info');
});

io.use(function(socket, next) {
  let found = _.findIndex(socketStore.connections, { 'userId': socket.request._query.userId });

if (parseInt(socket.request._query.userId) !== 0) {
  if (found < 0) {
    socketStore.connections.push({
      userId: parseInt(socket.request._query.userId),
      socket: socket
    });
  }
  else {
    socketStore.connections[found] = {
      userId: parseInt(socket.request._query.userId),
      socket: socket
    };
  }

  utils.logger(`User connected from ${socket.request.connection.remoteAddress}`, 'info');
  utils.logger(`User ${socket.request._query.userId} is now online!`, 'info');

    next();
  }
});

// Socket IO
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // some stuffs
});

app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

// Routes and Endpoints
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

And here is my default apache ssl config

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /root/ssl/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/ssl/example.com.key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message:

"Loading failed for the with source “https://example.com:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js”

is attempting to loading `/socket.io/socket.io.js` from an `HTTPS` server, but the code you show is for a socket.io server using `HTTP`, not `HTTPS`.  You don't show us the web page that this comes from, but the `<script>` tag for loading the socket.io.js library needs to be the same protocol as your socket.io server is listening for.

If you have an https server already, then you should just be using that for socket.io too.  There is no need to make a separate http server just for socket.io and, in fact, it's a bad practice to access `http` resources from an `https` page because it lies/deceives the user about the security of the page.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 thank you for your response. Yes I don't wanna left accessing socket io from non https while the domain is in https. I have updated my details above and have tried to use https on the socketio server, but unfortunately, it's still not working for me.

Comment: @TeodyC.Seguin - A couple things have me confused with your new code.  First, you need certificate credentials to start an https server.  Second, what is PHP doing in your HTML file?

Comment: hi @jfriend00, you mean on the socketio server needs to define the ssl credentials too? The is site built using PHP (together with some jQuery) and I am using socketio for realtime notifiations.